# Access 2010 using DoCmd.SendObject to send email

Tags: ms-access-2010

Using Access 2010, I have created a form that is functioning as a directory. I want to be able to click on a name field and send an email to that person. I have it working for one name on the directory but the second and third names fields give me the following error: Compile error: Method or data member not found. The highlighted portion of the code is: Private Sub AA2Name_Click(), while Me.AA2Email is highlighted in blue.

The full code is:

```
Private Sub AA1Name_Click()
 On Error GoTo Err_Handler

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, To:=Me.AA1Email

Exit_Handler:
 Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
 If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
 MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
 End If
 Resume Exit_Handler
 End Sub

Private Sub AA2Name_Click()
 On Error GoTo Err_Handler

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, To:=Me.AA2Email

Exit_Handler:
 Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
 If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
 MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
 End If
 Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub

Private Sub AA3Name_Click()
 On Error GoTo Err_Handler

DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, To:=Me.AA3Email

Exit_Handler:
 Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
 If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
 MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
 End If
 Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

Thank you to anyone that can help!

Answer (score 0):

I've recreated as best I can what from you've described above and it all ran ok for me. You can have a look at what I've got [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiUjY0c3ozTENwak0/view?usp=sharing) for clues; use the **frmEmails - original VBA** form.

The only thing I can think of is that you may have mistyped `Me.AA2Email` somewhere? Perhaps check the `Name` property of the control this is meant to refer to... does it appear in intellisense?

On a side note: I've created another version of the same form in that file called **frmEmails - updated VBA**. Here I've arranged your VBA so you're not duplicating so much code. Essentially it runs all the common code in to 1 subroutine, passing in the varying email field as an argument. This doesn't solve your problem, but I thought it was worth adding.

```vb
Public Sub ComposeEmail(ToField As String)

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, To:=ToField

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    End If
    Resume Exit_Handler

End Sub


Private Sub AA1Email_Click()

    ComposeEmail Me.AA1Email

End Sub


Private Sub AA2Email_Click()

    ComposeEmail Me.AA2Email

End Sub


Private Sub AA3Email_Click()

    ComposeEmail Me.AA3Email

End Sub
```